# Quartz scheduler - Different jobs using same class?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quarts examples usually do this:

```
JobDetail job = newJob(PrintMessageJob.class)
```

How can I create a job that has a param defined at runtime?  Something like this would be nice but is not allowed:

```
JobDetail job = newJob( new PrintMessageJob("my message") );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you must do is the following.

```
JobDetail job = newJob(PrintMessageJob.class)
               .usingJobData("message", "my message")
               .build();

public class PrintMessageJob implements Job {

    public PrintMessageJob() {
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        String message = dataMap.getString("message");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, that's helpful. But what if my Jobs need to operate on  instances of some objects instead?  I would like to do usingJobData("myThing", this) but only immutables (String, Double, etc) can be passed in that map.

Comment: I guess I could add all the objects I need to operate on to a static hashmap and then pass in the key when I create the job object so when the job runs it can get a reference to the instance to operate on.  That's not great either.

Comment: You should only do this if the hash and objects you put in the hashmap are immutable only.